# Typing the css function in styled-components

Tags: typescript, styled-components

I'm following the [example](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#media-templates) in the docs for creating media templates, and I'm really struggling to type the arguments to pass to the `css` function (plain JS version from example):

```
const sizes = {
  desktop: 992
}

const media = Object.keys(sizes).reduce((acc, label) => {

  acc[label] = (...args) => css`    // <----- how to type args

    @media(max-width: ${sizes[label]}px) {
      ${css(...args)}
    }

  `

  return acc
}, {})
```

In case you know TS but not styled-components, `args` is a tagged template literal, so I would use the `media` object as such:

```
media.desktop`
  background-color: blue;
  ${variable}
`
```

I have tried to type `args` as `TemplateStringsArray` but TS complains because spread arguments need to be of `array` type (which I think it is but somehow it is not recognised). If I change the type to `TemplateStringsArray[]`, the `css()` function complains because it expects at least 1 argument, but received 0 or more.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The signature for a tagged template should be `(literals: TemplateStringsArray, ...placeholders: any[]) => string` where `literals` are the strings in the template and `placeholders` are the variable values.

If you just want to pass all arguments to the `css` you can use `call`. Typescript will not let you spread directly because `css` has required arguments that the ts compiler tries to check for:

```
acc[label] = (...args: any[]) => css`  
  @media(max-width: ${sizes[label]}px) {
    ${css.call(undefined, ...args)}
  }

`
```

A fully typed version that correctly specifies the types for the `media.*` functions would be :

```
const sizes = {
    desktop: 992
}

const media = Object.keys(sizes).reduce((acc, label) => {

    acc[label] = (literals: TemplateStringsArray, ...placeholders: any[]) => css`      
    @media(max-width: ${sizes[label]}px) {
        ${css(literals, ...placeholders)}
    }

    `;
    return acc
}, {} as Record<keyof typeof sizes, (l: TemplateStringsArray, ...p: any[]) => string>)
```

Comment: Your first example is close to what I was working toward, but VSCode is saying "Expected at least 2 arguments, but got 1 or more" on the `...args` in the `call`. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: I ended up using your second example and it worked for me with a little modification. Some of the content I don't really understand to be honest. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 5):

The `Titian Cernicova-Dragomir` [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49397538/typing-the-css-function-in-styled-components/49398439#49398439) is great but doesn't work for me.
It produces a string with commas.
So I add `join` to `css` function.

```
import { css } from "styled-components";

const sizes = {
  desktop: 730,
};

const media = Object.keys(sizes).reduce(
  (acc, label) => {
    acc[label] = (literals: TemplateStringsArray, ...placeholders: any[]) =>
      css`
        @media (max-width: ${sizes[label]}px) {
          ${css(literals, ...placeholders)};
        }
      `.join("");
    return acc;
  },
  {} as Record<
    keyof typeof sizes,
    (l: TemplateStringsArray, ...p: any[]) => string
  >,
);

export default media;
```

Comment: this is exactly my issue where it automatically adds a comma at the end, your solution saved my day

Comment: This seems to have issues when using props inside the helper function.

Comment: I don't get where does it produce a string with commas? I'm not seeing anything